# Using reflection to create instance when using xmlbeans

Tags: java, reflection, xmlbeans

I've got a xsd file with over 100 types defined in it. I generated java code with xmlbeans binding, and then I can use

```
MyType.Factory.newInstance();
```

to get the class instance. But since there are too many types I've decide to use reflection to get create instances for each type.

I can now get the class(interface) of MyType using

```
Class clz = Class.forName("com.foo.MyType");
```

But have no idea of how to get the Factory class defined in the MyType interface and then get the new instance.

Any comment or hint is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the whole factory class (or more of it) and which classes you wish to instantiate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use the binary name to refer to inner classes: com.foo.MyType$Factory

Answer (score 1):

So, you have an inner class `Factory` declared inside your interface `MyType`? If I have that right, and if `Factory` is the only member class declared by `MyType', and if I understand what you're looking for, then the following should work.

```
clz.getDeclaredClasses( )[0].newInstance( );
```

**Edit:** Tested my answer out, and it works. I wasn't aware of the technique Pangea mentioned, but that works, too, and it's better than my answer. The code would look like this.

```
Class.forName("MyType$Factory").newInstance( );
```